# Problems reopening netcdf file written with xarray/dask

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I am running simulations using dask and store my output results in an xarray Dataset. Then I save the data to a netcdf file. 
Afterwards, I want to reopen the file for further data processing. Opening the file works, but when I actually access the data (e.g. calling `ds.compute()`), I get an error which seems to be related to reading in the file. I first thought that is was related to not properly closing the file after writing, but closing it manually does not help.

Strangely, I do not have any problem opening the file and using its data if the data is not produced with dask. If I just store a numpy array with random numbers in the Dataset, everything works fine.

I put together a small example so that you can have a look at it:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import dask.array as da
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from itertools import repeat

@dask.delayed
def run_sim(a, b, n_time):
    result = np.array([np.random.randn(n_time)*a,np.random.randn(n_time)+b])
    return result

client = Client()

# Parameters
n_sims = 5
n_time = 100
a_vals = np.random.randn(n_sims)
b_vals = np.random.randn(n_sims)
output_file = 'out.nc'

# if I use this as output, computing the data after reopening the file 
produces an error
out = da.stack([da.from_delayed(run_sim(*args), (2,n_time,),np.float64) for args in zip(a_vals, b_vals, repeat(n_time))])

# If I use this as output, reopening the netcdf file is no problem
#out = np.random.randn(n_sims,2,n_time) 

ds = xr.Dataset({'var1': (['realization', 'time'], out[:,0,:]),
                 'var2': (['realization', 'time'],out[:,1,:])},
                 coords={'realization': pd.RangeIndex(n_sims),
                         'time': pd.Index(np.arange(n_time)*.1)})


# Save to a netcdf file -> at this point, computations will be carried out
print('Saving data to netcdf file.')
ds.to_netcdf(output_file)

# close the netcdf file after writing
ds.close()

# Reopen the file
print('Reopen the file.')
with xr.open_dataset(output_file, chunks={'realization': 2}) as ds:
    # Now acces the data
    ds.compute()
```

The error I get is (I am just copying the last few lines, it is raised when trying to execute `ds.compute()`):

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py in _open_netcdf4_group()
    229     import netCDF4 as nc4
    230 
--> 231     ds = nc4.Dataset(filename, mode=mode, **kwargs)
    232 
    233     with close_on_error(ds):

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()

OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'/home/user/output/out.nc'
```

EDIT: 
If run the code only until closing the file (`ds.close()` is the last line executed) and the do a `ncdump -h` on the output file, I get an error saying that it is unable to open the file ('Resource temporarily unavailable'). So it still seems to be open somewhere.

Running the second part of the code (from `# Reopen the file` on) results in the above cited error.
But afterwards, `ncdump -h` on the output file is successful, yielding the expected output:

```
netcdf out {
dimensions:
    realization = 5 ;
    time = 100 ;
variables:
    double var1(realization, time) ;
            var1:_FillValue = NaN ;
    double var2(realization, time) ;
            var2:_FillValue = NaN ;
    int64 realization(realization) ;
    double time(time) ;
            time:_FillValue = NaN ;
}
```

If I then rerun the last part of the code again I do not get an error anymore.

Am I right in the following conclusions drawn from those results?

- The problem arises because the file is not properly closed after writing it.
- The first (unsuccessful) attempt to open the file at least closed it correctly.

If so, what can I do to circumvent this problem?

EDIT2:
The problem only arises if I start a dask.distributed.Client(). I also opened an [issue on the xarray GitHub page](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2376).

Comment: can you add the `ncdump -h` of you `output_file`? It would be good to understand if the error comes from the write or read part of this example.

Comment: @jhamman Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question and added the requested output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [this is a bug](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2376#issuecomment-415200809) which will be fixed. 
Installing the [branch](https://github.com/shoyer/xarray/tree/file-manager) which already contains the fix solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: The [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#netcdf) suggests that `close()` is only applicable when *reading* from a file.  When *writing* a file, `to_netcdf()` should handle closing the file for you.  I was going to put this in a comment, but don't have enough rep to make comments.

Comment: @m-neish Thanks for noting that. I was not sure if it is necessary when writing to a file. If `to_netcdf()` should take care of closing the file itself, there might be something wrong in the method?